# LSTM : multi-step multidimensional multivariate multi-site timeseries forecasting

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, multiple-regression, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm working on a project in which i'm trying to do a pollution forecasting. 
I googled around and found that LSTM is a good candidate for this task, however, I'm still struggling at how to adapt it to my particular problem.

My problem is as follows :

### Features :

- 109 measurement stations (in the same region) :

  - description (ex : typology, coordinates ...)
- 5 years of hourly data for each measurement stations :

  - weather data (ex : temperature, pressure, humidity, precipitation ...)
  - preliminary prediction of the target variables

### Target :

Hourly measurements of 4 pollutants (O3, NO2, PM10, PM25) for each site

### Goal :

Predict the daily value of each pollutant for each measurement site for the next 3 days

### My Questions :

**Q1. Multi-Site :** Is it a good idea to build a different model for each measurement site ? thus, ending up with 109 models and not taking advantage of the fact that close stations tend to have close measurements.

**Q2. Multivariate :** Should I build a NN for each pollutant ? or just one NN that outputs a vector of 4 ?

**Q3. Multi-step :** How do you adapt the LSTM to output the prediction the next 3 days ?

**Q4. :** Do I need to precise a time window ? I've read that LSTMs learn the timewindow by itself

**Q5. :** Is it better to transform the data by calculating the daily average then make a daily prediction OR make the hourly prediction then calculate the average ?